# speed up java maven compile on amazon clustering

Tags: java, maven, ant, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing

just a wild idea. wonder is it possible to compile maven build on amazon clustering machines to speed up build processes? any reference or guide on this?

[reference](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds)

Comment: You need to determine why it is your build takes so long.  Just compiling a million line program doesn't take that long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if it is possible to compile maven build on Amazon EC2 (...)

Yes, this is possible and I see more and more customer using on-demand instances for their CI machine.

Now, regarding Hudson build farms, while it's definitely possible to use a master/slave setup on several EC2 instances, I think that such a setup is especially nice if you have a high number of projects to build or huge build matrices. In other words, a master/slave setup allows to scale. But AFAIK, this won't allow you to distribute a single multi-modules build so this won't allow you to "speed up" such a build process.

Without more details on what you want to distribute/build exactly, it's hard to give a more precise answer.

Oh, by the way, if you want some real feedback on how Hudson is used at Sun, have a look at [Kohsuke Kawaguchi Hudson Webinar](http://www.build-doctor.com/2009/10/14/kohsuke-kawaguchi-hudson/). This will give you an idea of what it can do.